# Java Short to Byte Array

Tags: java, arrays, casting, byte, short

I have a
`short val = 150;`
how do I put this short into a byte[2]?

I have found some code examples because other people asked these question too, but none of them worked for me well.. please help me

Comment: You should post all the things you wrote to try this and explain specifically what's not working about each one.

Comment: So I guess we have to repeat all those examples that don't work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
short val = 150;
byte[] result = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(val).array();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
short val = 150;
byte []array = new byte[2]
array[0] = (byte)(val & 0xff);
array[1] = (byte)((val >> 8) & 0xff);
```

You are putting in array[0] the least significant byte. In array[1] the most significant byte.

For more about the meaning of the operations you can read [here](https://oscarliang.com/what-s-the-use-of-and-0xff-in-programming-c-plus-p/)

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, if I try this, i get the following output:

array[0] = -106
array[1] = 0

this doesnt make sense to me

Comment: Why not? What's the problem?

Comment: Could you maybe explain me each line of the code ? I really dont get it.. thank you

Comment: In the array[0] there will be the least significant part of bits. (the least significant byte). In array[1] the most significant. obviously you can invert if you prefer.
0xff means FF in hexdecimal.
For more about the meaning you read here: https://oscarliang.com/what-s-the-use-of-and-0xff-in-programming-c-plus-p/

Comment: Thank you very much. it worked for me all the time I just felt unconfortable with the fact that there were negative numbers in the byte array.. thank you!

Comment: I just did. Iam sorry Iam new to this forum